# Temp table creation issue in postgresql 11.6

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a PostgreSQL function I am creating a temp table named `table1` in a loop.

To check if the table already exist in other iterations I use the query `select * from pg_tables where tablename = '..'`.

But if the table does not exist during iteration (dropped in between) it still says the table exist. Is there any way to check if the table exist in a query rather than the mentioned query?

Query sample

```
db=# select * from pg_tables where tablename = 'table1';
 schemaname | tablename | tableowner | tablespace | hasindexes | hasrules | hastriggers |rowsecurity 
------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------
 pg_temp_3  |  table1    | user1        |user1 _data1  | t          | f        | f           | f
(1 row)

db=# \d table1
Did not find any relation named "table1".
```

This issue raises after  the function is interrupted by an exception. Any suggestions or findings?

Comment: Creating and dropping tables in a loop is more often than not a sign of a bad approach to begin with.

Comment: Did you try `create table if not exists...`?

Comment: let me explain some more. In my case i want to drop a column of that temp table  if that table exist, else create that table without that column.  query select * from pg_tables where tablename = 'table1' is used for that not for creating and dropping tables only . i am not dropping table either,it is a temp table across session it is not visible.  is this a bad approach?

Comment: Then how about "alter table1 drop column if exists _column_name_;" and get out of the loop. Or don't worry about it, it will not hurt anything just name he columns you want when needed (the way it should be done anyway). One might ask what is it doing there anyway, why was the unwanted column even created?

Comment: Actually this is a helper function let's call it function "c" IE. A function executed from another function, let's call the mother function "m" . when function "c" is called from function "m" for the first time we need to create that temp table, at the end of the function "c" a column is added and final result is created. When the next iteration from the function "m" starts in function "c" checks if that particular table exist. If the table exist drops that column and execution continues. Otherwise creates the table. I am using the query for that.